# Opening .txt file in Excel and keep all cells as Text Format

Tags: vba, excel, text, format

I am trying to open a .txt file in excel and keep all the cells as "Text" format. This is because there are values such as "Sept03" and it will convert it to "Sept-03" and when you force "Text" format after it has opened it converts it into number form ruining the data.

There is a lot of files and I need it to be automatic. Anyone have a solution or work-around for this? Can I force excel to open files and have all cells be a particular format before it fully opens?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the number of columns static or is there varying number of columns between TXT files? What is the delimiter? What is the code page? Have you looked into [Workbooks.OpenText method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx)?

Comment: The columns are not always the same, it is delimiter, and I haven't heard of the Workbooks.OpenText method. However, I did record a macro of using "Data Import: Text". After breaking it down, I got it to work. Thanks!